# JButton.setBackground isn't working

Tags: jbutton

```
JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("Game Time!");

    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4));

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setBackground(Color.RED);
            button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button.setOpaque(true);
            gamePanel.add(button,i,j);
        }
    }
```

I want to make the inside of the JButton the color red in this instance, but the code won't work, it just makes the borders around the JButtons red

Answer (score 0):

You have to change button.contentAreaFilled(false) to button.contentAreaFilled(true).